# Node Express app.js giving a 404 error for GET request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, get, http-status-code-404

I have looked at similar questions and they don't seem to answer my problem. I am getting a 404 error when I send a GET request. I have my router in a separate file and then calling my requests in my app.js.

I've tried to make my issue as simple as possible for this. Here's what I have:

movie-server.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const movieRouter = express.Router();

movieRouter
    .route('/movies')
    .get((req, res) => {
        res.send('hello from movies')
    })
module.exports = movieRouter;
```

app.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const movieRouter = require('./Movies/movie-server')

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello, world!') // this GET request works when I call it in Postman
})

app.use('/movies', movieRouter) // this returns a 404 Not Found error

module.exports = app
```

Here is the structure of my files:

[image: file structure]

I am not sure what I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

You are giving twice the `/movies` route, so your server will respond to http://host:port/movies/movies

The `movie-server.js` should contain:

```
const express = require('express')
const movieRouter = express.Router();

movieRouter
    .route('/') // Do not repeat /movies here
    .get((req, res) => {
        res.send('hello from movies')
    })
module.exports = movieRouter;
```

Comment: oh wow... I could have sworn you were supposed to specify the endpoint name in the router as well. Well thank you that solved my problem